# iOS loadHtmlString in UIWebView doesn't work with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a iOS app to load a html string which refer to external css file and javascript file in the same directory.

Here is my html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content= user-scalable="no", width="device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8"/> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjavascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

The css file works fine but it seems the js file never loaded. What could be the reason?

By the way I'm using loadHtmlString: BaseUrl method to load my html string.

Thanks

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012537/sourcing-local-javascript-in-uiwebview-ios?rq=1) link and hope its helpful as i have not tried that.

Comment: Can you show your iOS code for this?

Comment: Check to make sure that the javascript is in your *Copy Bundle Resources* section and not in the *Compile Sources* section.  I don't know why but sometimes Xcode thinks it should compile your Javascript.  Of course, it can't, so you just wind up with a bunch of no-op code and no resource for your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I end up without using embedded javascript. But I'll check your suggestion works or not.

Comment: It does work.  The two unaccepted answers which discuss moving .js files from "Compile Resources" to "Copy Bundle Resources" are correct; this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but since it has not been answered, I would like to point out that if you would like your web view to load a javascript file residing in your bundle, the way to do it is:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:html
               baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

If you don't specify the baseURL there is no chance that the javascript file is loaded.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. The problem is the javascript is still not loaded although the css is fine.

Comment: I see... are you sure that your javascript does not contain some errors? the issue with JS is that it fails silently. as a very raw debugging, you could put some alert statements in it (say, the first line in your js file), and see if they pop up...

Comment: Yes, I've test that by only add one line of JS code to alert.But it doesn't work. The CSS works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

By default, xcode will put new Javascript files in Compile Resources instead of Bundle Resources. Click on your project, then on your target. Under 'Build Phases' you may see the Javascript files under 'Compile Sources'. Drag them to down to 'Copy Bundle Resources'.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me when I dragged a few JS files into my project. I removed them from **Compile Resources** because Xcode was throwing an error, but without them being in **Bundle Resources**, they weren't available to my application. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

like the others have said

- use baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
- copy Bundle Resources and *not* in Compile Resources.

thats it!