# Display an HTML page containing Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift

In my iOS App, I would like to display an HTML containing javascript. It is an animated background.

I manage to display the HTML page inside a WKWebView but the javascript background is not displayed. The "Hello World" and the background color of the page is correctly displayed.

Can you help me ? (I don't know neither HTML nor Javascript)

Here is my viewDidLoad in Swift :

```
var webView = WKWebView()
do {
   let testHTML = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")
   let contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: testHTML!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
   let baseUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: testHTML!) //for load css file
   webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
} catch let error {
        print(error)
}
```

Here is my HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Homepage</title>

    <!--Add the new slick-theme.css if you want the default styling-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home_background.css"/>

  </head>
  <body class="home", bgcolor="#374283">
      <section class="canvas-wrap">
        <div class="canvas-content"></div>
        <div id="canvas" class="gradient"></div>
    </section>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <!-- Main library -->
    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Helpers -->
    <script src="js/projector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/canvas-renderer.js"></script>

    <!-- Visualitzation adjustments -->
    <script src="js/3d-lines-animation.js"></script>

    <!-- Animated background color -->
<script src="js/color.js"></script>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
  </body>
```

Thank you !

Comment: Hi @Nahouto , 
Check below link it's may help full to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14200594/2058242

Comment: Thank you, I will check that !