# ios webview, local html pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

im developing an ios app with uiwebview. the webview loads html pages placed locally. the html paged have used javascripts and jquery (mainly highcharts).
the app is unable to run the scripts.

```
NSString *urladdress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ad_aware_gulf_new_table" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urladdress];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

android has a setjavascriptenabled(true) but i couldnt find anything as such for ios.
solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the required .js files in your Xcode project.

This answer looks like it may help

[sourcing local javascript in uiwebview ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012537/sourcing-local-javascript-in-uiwebview-ios)